# Is it ok to ignore the promise returned by the process method of a bull queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bull.js

I use the [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) library to set up a processing queue, and when I use the `process` method for an existing queue I get a warning since this method returns a promise. I noticed bull's documentation ignores this return value and I want to know if it's safe to ignore such promise.

[image: Method signature for process method in bull library]

Other small questions, what can I expect if this function fails?
If I need to await for it to finish, this leads to issues since I would have to await the result everywhere, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Sounds like a question for their issue tracker, the lack of proper documentation is definitely worth reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/1688 (April 2020), committer manast answers Zikoel's question "Is not clear for me when the returned promise from `Queue.process` is resolved" with "in theory when the queue is closed." Because `process` starts the queue, [as dprentis notes](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/1688#issuecomment-663549902), the promise represents the status of the queue itself. The question has active team engagement from last week, so it is likely accurate to the maintainers' current understanding or intent.

For convenience, here's a link to the [Queue.process documentation](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#queueprocess). You're right that it does not demonstrate or acknowledge the return `Promise` from calls to `process`, despite being very careful to prescribe the Promise return requirements of the `processor` function to be passed in.

From a cursory look at the code ([Queue.run](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/a7f986f621c0680127b310df4894333188258f78/lib/queue.js#L868-L878)), it seems that `process` specifically resolves when the closure of the queue resolves the promises (number set by `concurrency`, default `1`) created as part of that single call to `process`. However, tests seem mostly to ignore the returned Promise or use it to [chain `catch` to signal test completion](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/a7f986f621c0680127b310df4894333188258f78/test/test_queue.js#L410); the few examples that use the returned promise [seem to be suppressed](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/a7f986f621c0680127b310df4894333188258f78/test/test_queue.js#L1545-L1572) or otherwise exceptional. Because that behavior appears to be officially undocumented and untested, you might not want to rely on it heavily.

Though it appears that it would not be a problem to ignore the returned Promises (as in the documentation and tests) or `await` any one of them to passively detect queue closure, you might also hedge your bets by collecting all of the returned promises into a `Promise.all` call and chaining `catch` to log any errors.